# Cannot save date: WordPress database error: [Column 'date' cannot be null]

Tags: php, wordpress

I trying to save some data from a simple form, into the database. So far all is well, a simple name and the email address, however I want to save the date in which the data was save into the database, but for some reason it's not working, I am getting this error, just as the title suggests:

> WordPress database error: [Column 'date' cannot be null]

Here's the code from the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_ebook_btn'])) {

        global $wpdb;
        
        $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'ebook_users';
        $name = $_POST['ebook_name'];
        $email = $_POST['ebook_email'];

        $insertDb = $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array(
          'name' => $name,
          'email' => $email,
          'date' => the_time('Ymd')
        ),
        array(
          '%s', 
          '%s', 
          '%s' 
        ));

     if($insertDb) { ?>
      <div>
        <h2>Download the ebook <a href="#">here</a></h2>
      </div>
    <?php } else {
      echo 'Something went wrong! Please try again.';
    }
}
```

2. Also, how would I redirect to a success/thank you page when the page is submitted? Sorry for the newbie question, fairly new with php.

Comment: The function `the_time()` doesn't return anything so the `'date'` value will be `null` (which is what the database complains about). It just outputs/echoes the response directly. If you want to store the response, you need to use [get_the_time()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_time/) instead. However, if the database column is a proper `date`-column in the database (with the type `date`, which it should be for storing dates), you need to use the format `Y-m-d`.

Answer (score 1):

The current time won't be returned without specifying a null value or else providing a specific time-zone such as $gmt.

function wp_date( $format, $timestamp = null, $timezone = null ) {
global $wp_locale;

```
if ( null === $timestamp ) {
    $timestamp = time();
} elseif ( ! is_numeric( $timestamp ) ) {
    return false;
}

if ( ! $timezone ) {
```

Comment: They aren't using `wp_date()` at all atm. (which they probably should be using though), but the second and third argument to that function (`$timestamp` and `$timezone`) are optional, not required since they have `null` as default values. Explicitly passing in `null` is therefore unnecessary.